# UNION query does not accept criteria to search date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a UNION query of three dates (1st_Exit, 2nd_Exit and 3rd_Exit. Then I made another query to enter criteria in Exit_Date column. When I run query it does show me result but would like to set criteria to enter the date I want. If I enter criteria like =[Enter date] there is no more result at all. Could you please help with this funny situation.

UNION query:

```
SELECT PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[1st_Exit_Date] AS Exit_Date FROM PresRec
GROUP BY PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[1st_Exit_Date] 
UNION
SELECT PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[2nd_Exit_Date] FROM PresRec
GROUP BY PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[2nd_Exit_Date]
UNION
SELECT PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[3rd_Exit_Date] FROM PresRec
GROUP BY PresRec.ID_Number, PresRec.[3rd_Exit_Date];
```

Simple query:

```
SELECT PresRecQ.ID_Number, Max(PresRecQ.Exit_Date) AS Exit_date
FROM PresRecQ
GROUP BY PresRecQ.ID_Number
HAVING (((Max(PresRecQ.Exit_Date)) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Could you please give some more clarity on the exact query which you're trying to execute is not pulling the records? Moreover, what's the expected output? What is simple query and union query you've shown here?

Comment: In which query are you using filter criteria? Edit question to show that attempt. Why have GROUP BY in UNION SELECT's when there is no data aggregation? Advise alias name not be same as field.

Comment: You are right about grouping records in UNION query. I just removed it. The purpose is to track how many people exits compound every day for reports. That is why I want to have an option to select date.

Comment: Why 3 date fields? This appears to be non-normalized structure, hence resorting to UNION. Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count exits by date then group on Exit_Date.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountExit, Exit_Date
FROM PresRecQ
GROUP BY Exit_Date;
```

To view all individual ID_Number values for a specific report, there is no need for grouping in query, just apply filter criteria on Exit_Date field.

Alternatively, build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping feature with aggregate calc in textbox. Report allows display of detail records as well as summary calcs.

Apply filter criteria to report to retrieve records of a specific date.

Comment: Thank you June7 I will definitely try your solution.